# How to copy from Excel and paste into Access using VBA-code (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I want to automate this process in order to reduce the risk of mistakes.

This is my first day I'm using VBA so my skills are somewhat lacking. I'm trying to automate some steps in my work, and therefore I need to copy 1 column from Access and paste it into an Excel worksheet. And after the mutations, I have to copy/paste the results back into Access (another column in the same Table). I've been looking for a working VBA code, and testing them, but until now I haven't found any.

`enter code here`
    Const TARGET_DB = "test.accdb"

```
Sub Test()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim MyConn
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Rw As Long

Sheets("Informatie").Select
Rw = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select

Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
MyConn = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & TARGET_DB

With cnn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .Open MyConn
End With

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
rst.Open Source:="Table1", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
Options:=adCmdTable

'Load all records from Excel to Access.
For i = 2 To Rw
rst.AddNew
For j = 1 To 7
rst(Cells(1, j).Value) = Cells(i, j).Value
Next j
rst.Update
Next i

'Close the connection
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing

MsgBox "Alan's work is finished for today"
```

I expected to see some mutations in the Access file. Any mutation would 
be a start. But nothing happened apart from the fact I selected the correct range in the Excel worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rw = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select
```

should be

```
Rw = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
```

Your original line would return -1 to Rw, so no data would be added.

If the added data needs to line up with the original data, this approach is probably not ideal - there's no guarantee that will happen.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that part of the code already worked. The only part that fails is the connection with Access, and selection of the correct Table/field within Acces.